# Open/close panel for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this:

```
// Show/hide filters on mobile //
$('#openMobileFilters').click(function(){   
    $('.navbar-inverse').addClass("hidden-xs"); 
    $('#results-container').addClass("hidden-xs");
    $('#filter-column').removeClass("hidden-xs");                       
});
$('.closeFilters').click(function(){
    $('#results-container').removeClass("hidden-xs");
    $('.navbar-inverse').removeClass("hidden-xs");      
    $('#filter-column').addClass("hidden-xs");          
});
```

All it does is hide a load of stuff onclick and show a filters div. Then closes it when the user clicks the `.closeFilters` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using toggleClass method

```
// Show/hide filters on mobile //
$('#openMobileFilters').click(function(){   
    showOrHideFilter(true);
});
$('.closeFilters').click(function(){
    showOrHideFilter(false);         
}); 

function showOrHideFilter(show) {
    $( "#results-container, .navbar-inverse" ).toggleClass( "hidden-xs", show );
    $('#filter-column').toggleClass("hidden-xs", !show); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works well and is more streamline. Do you think this is a good way of showing/hiding things for mobile? Or does bootstrap offer a better way?